# jQuery menu system - show submenu items without top level menu item expanding to fit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following menu system set up, it's pretty straight forward but as you can see the submenu items are larger than the top level items so when they are hovered the top level menu expands to allow for the submenu.

Is there a way to have the top level menu items stay a fixed width (they are being given a width from JS in another part of the project) and have the submenu item show underneath no matter how big it is without expanding the top level items.

It also has an issue where it fades in and out for each submenu item when you hover on these so it seems like it is flashing on screen one flash for each submenu item.

```js
var auth_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(2)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(2)").css("width", auth_width);
var cart_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(3)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(3)").css("width", cart_width);
var country_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(4)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(4)").css("width", country_width);

$("#nav > ul > li").unbind("mouseover").bind("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).find("ul").fadeIn();
});
$("#nav > ul > li").unbind("mouseout").bind("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).find("ul").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#nav{
float:right;
}

#nav > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#nav > ul > li > ul{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li>
        Item 1
    </li>
    <li>
        Item 2
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Item 3
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Item 4
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### Edit

I just added the section to show that the top level menu items are actually having their width set in another part of the script.

I need these widths to stay constant and for the entire element to be floated right.

Comment: You can just add `position: absolute` to your submenus -- with the menu floated to the right, you'll have to account for the width of the submenu in regards to the edge of the screen.  But without declaring `left`/`top` in the positioning, `absolute` will let the element just exist in its space on the screen without affected the parent: `#nav > ul > li > ul{ display:none; position: absolute; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the submenu(s) `position: absolute` -- this will let the submenu's exist in their own space, without conflicting with their parent elements.  However, with the menu being floated to the right, you will need to account for that (either use negative left margins `margin-left: -25px;` and/or set default widths for the submenus).

```js
var auth_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(2)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(2)").css("width", auth_width);
var cart_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(3)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(3)").css("width", cart_width);
var country_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(4)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(4)").css("width", country_width);

$("#nav > ul > li").unbind("mouseover").bind("mouseover", function(){
 $(this).find("ul").fadeIn();
});
$("#nav > ul > li").unbind("mouseout").bind("mouseout", function(){
 $(this).find("ul").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#nav{
float:right;
}

#nav > ul > li {
 display:inline-block;
 list-style:none;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#nav > ul > li > ul{
 display:none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
 <li>
  Item 1
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 2
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
   <li>Sub Item 2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 3
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
   <li>Sub Item 2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 4
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer that really helped. I am still having an issue with the submenu items flashing while hovering on these.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan this could be a couple of things (1) when the submenu comes into existence the cursor loses focus for a second (when the new menu appears) and it thinks (for a split second) that the element has been mouseout-ed. -- the fix: set the mouseout event on the submenu itself, and increase it's size (padding?) to cover up the parent element (2) the browsers can be rendering it funny based on when it wants fadein, it may activate `display: block` before incrementing the opacity from 0.0 -- the fix: write your own fadeIn/out in which you make sure that opacity starts at 0, then display

Comment: thanks again for your help. I changed my Mouseout function to  `$("#nav > ul > li > ul > li").unbind("mouseout").bind("mouseout", function(){$(this).fadeOut();}); ` but now it just fades out each individual submenu item when they are hovered and they don't reappear when hovering over the top level. However now I have a few things to try so thank you again

Comment: glad I could help :) (Also try stopping at just the nested ul? `#nav > ul > ul`)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use fix `width` attributes for navbar elements. Mostly this is enough due to the menu links and sublinks do not change very often (mostly....):

```js
$("#nav > ul > li").unbind("mouseover").bind("mouseover", function(){
 $(this).find("ul").fadeIn();
});
$("#nav > ul > li").unbind("mouseout").bind("mouseout", function(){
 $(this).find("ul").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#nav{
float:right;
}

#nav > ul > li {
 display:inline-block;
 list-style:none;
  vertical-align:top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80px;
}

#nav > ul > li > ul{
 display:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
 <li>
  Item 1
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 2
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
   <li>Sub Item 2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 3
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
   <li>Sub Item 2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 4
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately the top level menu has to remain small I can't set a fixed width that will allow for the submenu width. The top menu has to remain small and floated right but the submenu items can be up to half the width of the entire page so this won't work for me. I had been setting the width via javascript but it is the smaller original width I need

Comment: @PaddyHallihan oh ok sorry, i misunderstood the question. Give me a moment

Comment: @PaddyHallihan have a look at the other answers - do they provide your solution?

Comment: thanks the absolute positioning fixed the main issue of the widths. I'm still not sure about the second part of why it flashes for each submenu item. This can be seen better with more submenu items

Answer (score 0):

As Doug also stated use `position:absolute` to fix this:

```
#nav > ul > li > ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

Example:

```js
var auth_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(2)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(2)").css("width", auth_width);
var cart_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(3)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(3)").css("width", cart_width);
var country_width = $("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(4)").outerWidth();
$("#nav > ul:nth-child(3) > li:nth-child(4)").css("width", country_width);

$("#nav > ul > li").unbind("mouseover").bind("mouseover", function(){
 $(this).find("ul").fadeIn();
});
$("#nav > ul > li").unbind("mouseout").bind("mouseout", function(){
 $(this).find("ul").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#nav{
float:right;
}

#nav > ul > li {
 display:inline-block;
 list-style:none;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#nav > ul > li > ul{
 display:none;  
    position:absolute;
     width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
 <li>
  Item 1
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 2
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
   <li>Sub Item 2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 3
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
   <li>Sub Item 2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  Item 4
  <ul>
   <li>Sub Item 1</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for our answer, I am still trying to stop the submenu items from flashing though when trying to select these.